# How can I shorten my command line (bash/oh-my-zsh) prompt?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, bash, zsh

I have installed oh-my-zsh this morning and now command line is too long, it looks something like this:

my-username@my-pc-name ~/Desktop/

I would like to change "my-username@my-pcname ~" part just to "~".

I have done it on my Linux Mint but can't make it work here. I have edited my .bashrc file (following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt) instructions) but changes wont take effect.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://superuser.com/questions/874669/oh-my-zsh-terminal-how-to-change-prefix-suffix-of-new-prompt-window

Answer (score 1):

Okey i just realized that editing .bashrc file was bad idea, i c/p .zshrc file from Mint and it works like charm.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/hkFJDQGg) you can find pastebin of file if someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your bash prompt by editing PS1 variable.
[Follow this link](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Changing_bash_prompt)

THis is how mine looks like

```
Thu Mar 31 02:04 PM asiri:~$
```

Releated ps1 is

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\d \@ \u:\W\$ '
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to ~/.zshrc

```
prompt_dir() {
  prompt_segment yellow $CURRENT_FG '%2~'
}
```

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.